# React-native-map conditional marker icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm rendering markers into a react-native-map app. So I have in the backend API a defined type for each marker. Now I want to display them using customised icons.

Currently I render each type separately. Kind like this

```
//from API
this.setState({MyMarkers: (response.data)})

Type1mapMarkers = () => {
        return this.state.MyMarkers.filter( report => report.type === 'type1').map((report) =>
                <Marker
                    key={report.id}
                    coordinate={{ latitude: report.latitude, longitude:report.longitude }}
                    title={report.name}
                    description={report.info}
                    icon={require("../statics/icons/type1.png")}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={require("../statics/icons/type1.png")}
                        style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                    />
                </Marker >)
    }
Type2mapMarkers = () => {
        return this.state.MyMarkers.filter( report => report.type === 'type2').map((report) =>
            <Marker
                    key={report.id}
                    coordinate={{ latitude: report.latitude, longitude:report.longitude }}
                    title={report.name}
                    icon={require("../statics/icons/type2.png")}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={require("../statics/icons/type2.png")}
                        style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                    />
                </Marker >)
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <SafeAreaView >
                <View>
                    <MapView
                        ...
                    >
                        {this.Type1mapMarkers()}
                        {this.Type2mapMarkers()}
                    </MapView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
```

Is there a way to work with an if statement in the rendering instead? I've tested a few options but not been succcesful. Any tips? What I'm trying to achieve is something like

```
this.setState({MyMarkers: (response.data)})

MapMarkers = () => {
        return this.state.MyMarkers.map((report) =>
             if (){
             <Marker>
               ....
             </Marker>}{
             <Marker>
               ....
             </Marker>}
   }

    render() {

        return (
            <SafeAreaView >
                <View>
                    <MapView
                        ...
                    >
                        {this.MapMarkers()}
                    </MapView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a straight-forward approach:

```
render() {

  const { MyMarkers } = this.state

  return <MapView>
      {MyMarkers?.map( report => 
               <Marker
                    ...
                    icon={require(`../statics/icons/${report.type}.png` )}
                >
                    <Image source={require(`../statics/icons/${report.type}.png`)} />
                </Marker>)}
   </MapView>
}
```

Note the use of string interpolation with `

Comment: Good suggestion. I didn't think of that possibility. But I can't get the dynamic interpolation to work.

Comment: log the URI's to the console to check if they are correct: 
MyMarkers?.forEach( ({ type }) => console.info( 'uri', `../statics/icons/${type}.png` ) )

Comment: I instead went with static path's. source={IconImages[report.type]} based on rendered constant         const IconImages = {
            Type1:require("../statics/icons/Type1.png"),
            Type2: require("../statics/icons/Type2.png"),
        };

Comment: this approach is not future-proof, should you need further types

Comment: correct. good point. but since the icon images are not created dynamically. They will anyway have to be created and uploaded (unless I use a linked icon). So if a new type is added updates will be necessary anyway. The Types are anyway not dynamic in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Injecteer gave me the solution. But I made one adjustment to be able to have static path's.

```
const IconImages = {
    Type1:require("../statics/icons/Type1.png"),
    Type2: require("../statics/icons/Type2.png"),
...
}

class .....

render() {

  const { MyMarkers } = this.state

  return <MapView>
      {MyMarkers?.map( report => 
               <Marker
                    ...
                    icon={IconImages(report.type)}
                >
                    <Image source={IconImages(report.type)} />
                </Marker>)}
   </MapView>
}

export....
```

Comment: define your `IconImages` constant outside of your class-body, to make it more performant